# sed delete string matching a variable value containing slashes

Tags: sed, ksh

I'm trying to use sed to clean a list.  Any lines appearing in $salvation should be removed from the already set $naughtyList.

I have;

```
$ echo "$naughtyList"
ONE/1/one
TWO/2/two
THREE/3/three
FOUR/4/four
FIVE/5/five
```

and;

```
$ echo "$salvation"
TWO/2/two
FOUR/4/four
```

The problem is the slash characters.  I can't escape them when trying;

```
for line in $(echo $salvation); do
naughtyList=$(echo $naughtyList | sed "/$line/d")
done
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `2'
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown command: `4'
```

Is there a way to pass $line, or do I have to modify the input patterns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use `grep -f` here with process substitution:

```
grep -vFf <(echo "$salvation") <(echo "$naughtyList")
ONE/1/one
THREE/3/three
FIVE/5/five
```

To update `naughtyList` variable, use:

```
naughtyList=$(grep -vFf <(echo "$salvation") <(echo "$naughtyList"))
```

Comment: Wow. I never knew grep could do that.  Thanks so much - works a treat!